# How to initialize the parameter in the cross validation method and get the final model after training and evaluating using this method?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

As I learned about **cross-validation** algorithm, from most of the articles on the web, there are variety of **cross-validation** methods. Here I want to be clear about the ***k-fold cross-validation*** technique.

In the ***k-fold cross-validation*** algorithm, we can split the training set in to *k* not-overlapped folds.

As we split the training data in to *k* folds, we have to train the model in *k* **iterations**.

So, in each iteration, we **train** the model with **(k-1) folds** and ***validate*** it with the ***remained fold***.

In each split we can calculate the desired metric(s) of our model.

At the end we can report the **training error** by taking the average of scores of all iterations.
But what is the **final trained model**?

Some points in those articles are not clear for me?

1. Should I **initiate model's parameters in each iteration**?
   I ask this, because if I don’t initialize the parameter's it could save the pattern of data which I want to be unseen in the next iteration and so on…
2. Should I save the **initial parameter of the split in which I gained the best score**, as the best initial values of the parameters?
3. Should I retrain the model initiating it with the initial values of the parameters gained in my second question and then feed it with whole training dataset and gain the **final trained model**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut
As you have read the first line of help center it says :"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". And I did so! In fact the cross validation ready-to-use algorithms are already exist in different libraries, but what I tried to get clear understanding about, is to know how does this algorithm exactly works and how can I implement it in my own project! So it is exactly about programming.

Comment: I am afraid there is no *programming* issue here, only ML methodological ones; and If I have some "*practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*" about non-programming issues, this is not the place to ask (we have no less than 3 (!) SE sites dedicated to such issues). Finally, regardless of the above, you are asking 3 different questions, which in itself makes your post eligible for closing as "needs focus".

Answer (score 2):

Alright so before answering your question I will go a bit back to explain the purpose of cross validation and model evaluation. You can read [these slides](https://bengio.abracadoudou.com/lectures/old/tex_theory.pdf) or research more about *statistical learning theory* if you want to go deeper.

#### Train/test split

Suppose you have a model with defined hyperparameter (or none) and you train it on the training split. If you calculate the metrics over the test split, this will give you the risk of the model on new data. Then you know that this particular model will perform like that on unseen data.

So we have a learning process B, that takes a dataset S (here the training dataset) as well as hyperparameters h, and gives a fitted model m; then **B(S, h)->m** (training B on S with hp h gives a model m, with its parameters). Then we tested this model to evaluate the risk R on the test dataset.

#### k-fold Cross validation

When doing k-fold cross validation, you fit **k** models using the learning process B. Each model is fitted on a different training set, and the risk is computed on non overlapping samples.

Then, you calculate the mean risk among the folds. A common mistake is that it gives you the performance of the model, that's not true. This gives you the mean (or expected) performances of the learning process B (and hyperparams h). That means, **if you train a new model using B (and hyperparams h), its expected performance will be around the calculated metrics** (of course this is not always true).

#### For your questions

1. Yes you should train the model from scratch, if possible with the same initial parameters (if initialization is not random) to avoid any difference between folds. Using a warm start with the previous parameters can modify the learning process, and the fitting.
2. No, if initialization is random let it be, if it is fixed use the same initial parameters for all folds

For the two previous questions, if by *initial parameters* you meant **hyperparameters**, then you should keep the same for all folds, otherwise the calculated risk will be useless. If you want to try multiple hyperparameters, you have to repeat the cross validation multiple times, and then you can select the best ones based on the risk calculated.

3. Once you tuned your hyperparameters you can train the model on your whole training set. This will give you a model m. Before your cross validation you can keep a small test split to evaluate this final model on unseen data